# Ubuntu 19.04 apt broken dependency: mono

Tags: linux, ubuntu, installation, apt, mono-framework

I'm having an issue with apt on ubuntu 19.04. Every time I try to install or upgrade an apt package the following error comes up:

```
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mono-complete : Depends: mono-roslyn (= 6.4.0.198-0xamarin3+ubuntu1804b1) but it is not going to be installed
 mono-devel : Depends: mono-roslyn (= 6.4.0.198-0xamarin3+ubuntu1804b1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

When running `sudo apt -f install` I am met with the following error:

```
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/mono-roslyn_6.4.0.198-0xamarin3+ubuntu1804b1_all.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/csc', which is also in package chicken-bin 4.13.0-1
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/mono-roslyn_6.4.0.198-0xamarin3+ubuntu1804b1_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

In short: `mono-roslyn` is trying to over write the `csc` binary, which is currently used by `chicken-bin` (the CHICKEN scheme compiler).

I have tried moving the `csc` binary from `/usr/bin/csc` to `/usr/bin/csc-chicken` to check if that would fix the issue. It did not, and I still have the same error occur.

I have had issues regarding apt and mono before, which I fixed with `sudo apt autoremove`, with gives me the same error as the first shown here.

I need to fix this issue in order to be able to upgrade or install new packages on my system. As you can imagine this is a rather pressing matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few days I have come to a solution. I decided to just remove `chicken-bin` so that mono could install correctly (not ideal, but my best option). As I said in my question `apt remove` would not work, but I figured out that I could remove the package using `dpkg`.

The following commands fixed my issue:

```
$ sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq chicken-bin
$ sudo apt -f install
```

Hopefully someone else finds this useful.